# Getting Error Code 400 Bad Request for Rest WCF Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I am working on a application which send request to wcf rest service through get and post method. In my case, the `GET` method is working fine. But in `POST` method, I am always getting error code `400 Bad Request`.

My Client Side Code :-

```
    string strInput = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab");
    byte[] data = GetBytes(strInput);
    //data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strInput);
    data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInput);



    Stream objStream;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9010/SampleServices/Service/Test/Category/Add");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-urlencoded";
    objStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    objStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    objStream.Close();


    WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream());
    string response = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
    responseStream.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(response);
```

Server Side Code :-

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Category/{categoryID}", Method = "GET")]
        Category GetCategory(string CategoryID);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Category/Add", Method = "POST")]
        bool AddCategory(string category);
   }


public class Service : IService
    {
        public Category GetCategory(string categoryID)
        {
            NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext();
            var category = context.Categories.SingleOrDefault(e => e.CategoryID == Convert.ToInt32(categoryID));
            context.Dispose();
            return category;
        }

        public bool AddCategory(string category)
        {
            //NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext();
            //context.Categories.InsertOnSubmit(category);
            //context.SubmitChanges();
            //context.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I tried with different options for content type and also tried with Url encoding for the parameter string but still getting the same issue. What can be the reason behind that as the `HttpGet` is working fine. Why there is an issue with `HttpPost`?

WCF Configuration :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SampleServices.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MYServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:12000/SampleServices/Service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingDetails" contract="SampleServices.IService" behaviorConfiguration="TCPBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="webHttpBinding" address="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior" contract="SampleServices.IService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9002/SampleServices/Service/" />
          </baseAddresses>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="01:20:10" openTimeout="01:20:00" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TCPBindingDetails" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" maxBufferSize="5000000" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <clear />
        <behavior name="TCPBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MYServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post you web.config file as well

Comment: It is a windows application and nothing important in configuration file

Comment: WCF Service Web.config?

Comment: One update, Post method is also working fine if there is no parameter in the requested method, but if it contain parameter/signature than returning as bad request

Answer (score 0):

There are many cause for this kind of error. Try to change the metadata like below -

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Category/Add", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
bool AddCategory(string category);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some articles indicating you need to use a webHttpBinding for this to work. It may help